# How to send Header using HTTP in JAVA

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have this command.

```
# curl --header "Authorization: key=$api_key" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send  -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"
```

it is sending push notification in my device. Now I am trying java to sending it but my code is not working.

```
String body = "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}";
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
StringEntity stringentity = new StringEntity(body, "UTF-8");

httppost.addHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
    httppost.addHeader("Authorization: key", "AIza*********YUI");
httppost.setEntity(stringentity);
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    String strresponse = null;
    if (entity != null) {
        strresponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        System.out.println("strresponse = "+strresponse);
    }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am confuse what i am missing. This doc http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html#request told that i needs to send header with body.

Comment: What do ou mean but `but my code is not `? Is there any exceptions thrown? Is there any results that you experience? How can we help if you're not telling us what is **actually** wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your `curl` example, this should be your `Authorization` header:

```
httppost.addHeader("Authorization", "key=AIza*********YUI");
```

This should resolve your issue. I just confirmed this header with the referenced [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html#auth).